# Connecting to People Search through Tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

We are creating a report that would need employee information. We have the employee ID, but we are also looking for the name and office location. Is it possible to have tableau hit people search to pull this information?

Comment: ofcourse, you need to join the People database table with your employee table

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wildcard Match Filter Function to do so.

[image: 1]

Then, when you type employee ID in the search box, it will filter it out to dashboard.